# Flink CEP: How to check if next event didn't appear in given time window?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I'm trying to find out how to implement the following logic having stream of events:

1. First event appear in given time window(30s)
2. Second event that is related to the first one(by some property) **didn't appear** in given time window
3. Generate new error event

Currently I implemented the "opposite" implementation which was pretty easy:

```
stream.begin('first').where({conditions}).next('second').where({conditions}).within(Time.seconds(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `PatternTimeoutFunction` to generate new events when the events aren't received in the time window. More about this type of functions and how to use it here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/cep/PatternTimeoutFunction.html.